# How can I fix the black screen I see when trying to update WhatsApp status?

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-635

I tried several times to pick a picture from my phone gallery and set it as my WhatsApp status. But, whenever I try to do that I could only see a black screen with no photo gallery visible at all.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking updates for WhatsApp? Or uninstalling and reinstalling WhatsApp? I'm amazed that you don't have  picker. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX610.png

Comment: I just did and there's no picker again

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a glitch either your phone may have or a bug in the app itself. If it is your phone that is the culprit, then it can be easily fixed by either restarting or soft resetting your phone. A soft reset can be done by holding Volume Up button + Power button at the same time for about 10-15 seconds.

If, however, that didn't fixed your problem, then it should be a WhatsApp bug that you may report it to them.